# Is it possible close the main swf window?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a main swf in which i create an external Air NativeWindow. How can i close this main swf from the second window or directly at the end of the function calling?

I tried the `fscommamd("quit")`, `exit()` etc. but I think they cannot be used in this sense.

Otherwise tell me a method to scretch the main swf to fit the screen resolution that may change, if exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another website, hope it's usefull for you:
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?295486-fscommand%28-quot-quit-quot-%29-in-AS3-pls-help

```
import flash.system.fscommand;


private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
     fscommand("quit");
}
```